# MySql: remove table rows depending on column duplicate values?

Tags: sql, mysql, duplicates

I have a table with year column and this column shouldn't have duplicate values. So I end up with a table with only one 2007 year record for example.

So how could I delete those rows that have duplicate year value?

Thanks

Comment: if you have for example 3 duplicate rows to year 2008 , which rows you decide to delete ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18932/80714 The answer there is clear and concise.

Comment: This is not the same question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you could simply try adding a UNIQUE INDEX using IGNORE:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`column`);
```

MySQL should respond with something like:

```
Query OK, 4524 rows affected (1.09 sec)
Records: 4524 Duplicates: 9342 Warnings: 0
```

Of course, you'll leave it up to MySQL to decide which rows to drop.

EDIT:

this works for as many columns as you like:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`);
```

check MySQL's documentation on [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html). A common gotcha (at least one I ran into once) is to forget that `NULL = NULL` isn't true (but `NULL`), hence {42, NULL} and {42, NULL} are allowed for a UNIQUE index on two columns.

Comment: Thanks work perfectly, but Is it possible to apply it on two columns?

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer works perfectly, but `IGNORE` keywords id **depreciated** now([Source](http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7395)), it will not work after MySQL 5.6(may be).

Although `alter table` option is very easy and direct BUT, Now only option is to create new table by a query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name> AS SELECT * FROM <your_table> GROUP BY col1,col2,col3;
```

After that you can delete `<your_table>` and rename `<table_name>` to your table.

Here you can change the column list in `Group By` clause according to your need(from all columns to one column, or few columns which have duplicate values together).

**Here I also want to mention a point:**

1. unique index does not make change in row if any columns(from index, like here 3 columns) have `null` as value. Ex: `null,1,"asdsa"` can be stored twice
2. same way if you have single column in unique index then multiple rows with `null` values(for that column) will remains in table
3. The plus point with `create table` is, it will work with null values also.

Answer (score -1):

'GROUP BY' does not work if any select columns do not have a dependency on  the 'group by' columns. See 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' sql_mode.  You can change the sql_mode but I was not able to do this with knex (my ORM).  I ended up doing the filtering of the returned sql results in code.